# How to display the getter as text in the template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I have a getter, which I would like to display in the template as text.

The data is already in the getter, checked with devtools vue chrome extension.
The data I want to get from the getter looks like this:

```
["appel", "banaan", "kiwi"]
```

My component looks like this: (the name of getter is getPlaylist)

```
<template>
    <div>
      <span>{{ showPlaylist }}</span>
    </div>
<template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("app"["getPlaylist"]),

     showPlaylist() {
       this.getPlaylist;
     },
  },
};
</script>
```

How can I use this getter to show the text of the array?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to display this ["appel", "banaan", "kiwi"] in the template
If yes, modify the code to

```
computed: {
...mapGetters("app"["getPlaylist"]),

 showPlaylist() {
  return this.getPlaylist;
 },
```

}

Comment: That won't work as you have nested `"` in your string...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're hoping to get with `...mapGetters("app"["getPlaylist"])`, but I can't see it doing anything else other than being an undefined

`"app"` is a string, which doesn't behave like an object or array. the only thing available that could be accessed is string methods (ie `"app"["startsWith"]("a")`) or characters `"app"[2]`)

if `app` is a module and `getPlaylist` the getter, you need to define it as:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["app/getPlaylist"]),
}
```

alternatively if `app` is another getter...

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["app","getPlaylist"]),
}
```

or if `app` is a namespace

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters("app",["getPlaylist"]),
}
```

Comment: Solved I was missing a (,)

this is the solution:

...mapGetters("app", ["getPlaylist"]),

Comment: so app is a namespace?